# Переменная в URL

Tags: google-apps-script

Как правильно задать переменную в google apps script для URL?
Пробую так:

```
function getData() {
var cell1 = "AHL-D";
var url = "http://quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol="cell1"&sopt=symbol";
```

Не работает, выдает ошибку "Перед оператором отсутствует точка с запятой. (строка 3" , Хотя вроде все точки с запятой на месте.

Comment: Где вы после этого ``var url = "http://quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol="`` увидели ``;``? Лично  я не вижу.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk, это ошибка линтера - он реагирует первым. В общем-то, обычно он это и сообщает, когда пропущен оператор. Без него ошибка будет `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно

```
function getData() {
  var cell1 = "AHL-D";
  var url = "http://quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=" + 
    cell1 + "&sopt=symbol";
  ...
}
```